# Allow Customer Portal users to add photos of themselves in My Settings?

Tags: chatter, customer-portal

I can't figure this out.[image]

Photo is grayed out and you can't edit it. Same with title. I don't know where "My Settings" are sourced from for customer portal users. How can I allow them to edit this?

Comment: this looks more like lightning comuities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are confusing the "My Settings" page with "My Profile", which is used to control visibility settings. if they select my profile, users should be able to upload their photo:

[image]